# Validar en dos grupos diferentes de radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, validación

Hola muy buenas tardes  tengo un formulario de acerca de 28 preguntas en la cual cada pregunta cuenta con dos respuestas que esta organizada por grupos, lo que quiero intentar es de que las respuestas no se traslapen ver en imagen adjunta 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ando buscando como validarlo para que en cuanto esten en el mismo renglon indique que no es permitido, un grupo es para las respuestas de MOST y el otro de LEAST aqui dejo el mark up:

```
    <input type="radio" name="most_option_1" id="q1_most_option_id_1" value="D">
<input type="radio" name="least_option_1" id="q1_least_option_id_1" value="C">
```

Espero que alguien me pueda orientar.  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo deseas que se pueda seleccionar un `radio` por cada `<td>` en la tabla, debes colocarle a ambos el mismo atributo `name` y diferente `value` para poder saber cuál escogió. Los mismos formularios de HTML se encargarán que el usuario no pueda escoger más de un `radio`.

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input

> `radio`: Botón radio. Debes de usar el attributo **value** para defenir el valor que va a ser enviado por este elemento. Usa el atributo **checked** para determinar si un elemento debe de ser seleccionado por defecto. Botones radio que tengan el mismo valor en el atributo **name**, se considera que están en el mismo "grupo de botones radio", por lo que solo una opción puede ser seleccionada a la vez.

Ejemplo:

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pregunta</th>
      <th>Most</th>
      <th>Least</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Pregunta #1</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p1" value="M"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p1" value="L"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pregunta #2</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p2" value="M"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p2" value="L"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pregunta #3</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p3" value="M"></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="p3" value="L"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo que ando buscando has de cuenta en el grupo de Most solo se puede seleccionar una sola opcion y en la de least lo mismo, pero no se pueden seleccionar ambas que esten en la misma altura del renglon, no se si me explique asi como esta en la imagen con el recuadro rojo asi no pueden de estar, con que mande mensaje y no deje de poner el submit con eso es suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner el mismo valor en "name".

```
  <input type="radio" name="most_option_1" id="q1_most_option_id_1" value="D">
  <input type="radio" name="most_option_1" id="q1_least_option_id_1" value="C">
```